# Image slider for variable width images with previous and next images partly visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, slider

I have been trying to get jquery.ad-gallery.js to display the previous and next images opaqued (or part of them) as is being done at http://www.tyinarchitects.com/ (That site is rather odd, and uses an old and modified script) but I have had no luck modifying the demo (http://coffeescripter.com/code/ad-gallery/). 
I have tried a wider gallery, and various display:block and overflow:visible and have commented out line 490 of the script as per a previous post, but to no avail.

Does anyone have an example I can look at or any hints on how to do this or failing this does anyone know of a slider which shows a full sized middle image centred with partial views of the previous and next images. Crucially it must support variable width images with the same height, which seems a problem with all the sliders I have looked at.
Thanks

Comment: You should provide code that you've tried. Maybe attempt to write your own slider which will look and act exactly how you want it to?

Comment: it will be great if you can show us what you have done so far. sometimes one little thing can make the code not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, answering my own question may not be good form – but the page I referenced has been quite heavily modified to do something the original plugin was (as far as I can see) never designed to do.